# dropdown list empty when id is autocompleted

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

A button "add tarification" already selected leads us to this interface below which allows us to add a "tarification" after having selected the "metier" and the "tache" in question. The technician id box is auto-completed. My problem is that I always find the "Metier" list empty.

BUT When I manually select a technician id the metier list is no longer empty.
Thanks.

Note that each technician has a list of metier and each "metier" has a list of related tache

[image]

**tarificationcontroller.php**

```
public function create($technicien_id = null)   
{
    $technicien = technicien::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
 $taches = Tache::orderBy('libelle_tache', 'asc')->get();
    $metiers = Metier::orderBy('libelle_metier', 'asc')->get();
    >with('technicien', $technicien)->with('metiers', $metiers)- 
    >with('technicien_id', $technicien_id);
}
```

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
@if(count($errors))
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
<ul>
@foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
<li>{{$message}}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
</div>
@endif
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" 
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var getMetiersByTechnicienUrl = "{{url('/metiersbytechnicien')}}";
var getTachesByMetierUrl = "{{url('/tachesbymetier')}}";
//console.log(getMetiersByTechnicienUrl,getTachesByMetierUrl 
,getTarificationsByTacheUrl);
function getMetiersByTechnicien(val) {
if(val.length>0) {
    var technicien_id = val;
    $.get(getMetiersByTechnicienUrl+'/'+technicien_id,function(res) 
{ var html = '<option value=">-Select-"' ; 
$.each(res.metiers,function(index,item) { 
html+=''+item.libelle_metier+''; }); $('#metiers').html(html);

    });
}
}

function getTachesByMetier(val) {
if(val.length>0) {
    var metier_id = val;
    $.get(getTachesByMetierUrl+'/'+metier_id,function(res) {
        var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
        $.each(res.taches,function(index,item) {
            html+='<option 
value="'+item.id+'">'+item.libelle_tache+'</option>';
        });
        $('#taches').html(html);

    });
}
}
</script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="col-md-12">

<div class="col-md-10">
    <h1>Tarification tache</h1>
<form action=" {{url ('tarification')  }}" method="post">
 {{csrf_field()}}
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="technicien">Technicien</label>
       <select onchange="getMetiersByTechnicien(this.value)" 
 name="technicien_id" id="technicien_id" class="form-control">
               <option value="">-Select-</option>
               @foreach($technicien as $t)
                      <option value="{{$t->id }}" {{ $t->id == 
 $technicien_id ? 'selected = "selected"' : '' }}>
                            {{$t->user->nom}}
                      </option>
               @endforeach
        </select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Metier: </label>
    <select onchange="getTachesByMetier(this.value)" style="width: 
 200px" class="productm form-control" id="metiers">
        <option value="">-Select-</option>
   </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">                                      
                <label>tache: </label>
                <select style="width: 200px" class="productname 
  form-control" name="tache_id" id="taches">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>tarification: </label>
                <input style="width: 200px" class="productname form- 
  control" type="text"  name ="Tarif" class="form-control" value=" 
  {{old('tarif')}}">

 </div>
 </div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form-control 
   btn btn-primary">
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>

       </div>
<link 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/    
bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
@endsection
```

**metiercontroler.php**

```
public function getMetiersByTechnicien($technicien_id)
{

    $t = technicien::find($technicien_id);
    return response()->json(['metiers' => $t->metier]);
}
```

**route.php**

```
Route::get('tarification/create/{technicien_id?}', 
'TarificationController@create');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the technician select, you are populating it with technician data as shown below:

```
@foreach($technicien as $t)
            <option value="{{$t->id }}" {{ $t->id == 
 $technicien_id ? 'selected = "selected"' : '' }}>
             {{$t->user->nom}}
             </option>
 @endforeach
```

For the metier select, no data is passed hence when you check the select no data is available:

```
<select onchange="getTachesByMetier(this.value)" style="width: 
 200px" class="productm form-control" id="metiers">
        <option value="">-Select-</option>
</select>
```

What you need to do is this:

- Since you already know the technician who will be selected by default on the technician select, find all the jobs for them (you already have the code to do that *getMetiersByTechnicien($technicien_id)* in your controller) therefore pass this data and populate the jobs select on load.

The technician select does not change on load therefore the onChange() event will only be trigger when you manually change the technician select.

I hope this solves your issue, if it does please mark my answer ;)

Comment: "therefore pass this data and populate the jobs select on load" I didn't really get it, can you explain me with an example code @Leo

Comment: The same way you passed the $technicien variable to your view, pass another variable $jobs and do the following:

<label>Metier: </label>
    <select onchange="getTachesByMetier(this.value)" style="width: 
 200px" class="productm form-control" id="metiers">
        <option value="0" 'selecte'>-Select-</option>
@foreach($jobs as $job)
            <option value="{{$job->id }}">
             {{$job->name}}
             </option>
 @endforeach
   </select>

Remember, this will be done on page load hence this is how you will declare your select box for jobs. I hope this helps

Comment: it didn't worked, sorry but it's not very clear @Leo

Comment: Ok, lets start from the top and do this step by step. Did you pass the list of jobs only applicable to the technician that is automatically selected on the Technicien select box when the form loads?

Comment: I think I could understand if you give me some code @Leo

Comment: Do you have something like this?

/**
     * Show the view for this controller
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function view() {      
         return view('client.reps');
    }